# A reviewer of my code said the code working fine except it is failing for one edge case

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures

> Algorithms & Data Structures. This venture covers an assortment of
>   subjects identified with the information structures. I have composed a
>   perfect and productive answer in Python, just as a content
>   clarification of the proficiency of my code and my structure
>   decisions.

### Explanation

I have implemented the Huffman encoding technique herewith the following steps: i) Calculate the occurrence of each character in a string. ii) The character with the highest occurrence is encoded with minimum code length ie 1 then next Character as 01 and then 001 and so on.

Time Complexity
Time complexity: O(n)

Space Complexity
Space complexity: O(distinct_characters)

---

I am seeking better explanations of this.

```
import sys
global huff

def huffman_encoding(data):
    global huff
    huff = {}
    for char in data:
        huff[char] = huff.get(char, 0) + 1
    tree = {}
    temp = '1'
    for num in sorted(huff.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]):
        tree[num[0]] = temp
        temp = '0' + temp

    encode = ''
    for d in data:
        encode += tree[d]
    return encode, tree

def huffman_decoding(data,tree):
    huff = {}
    for char in tree:
        huff[tree[char]] = char
    #print(huff)
    temp = ''
    decode = ''
    for d in data:
        if d == '1':
            decode += huff[temp + d]
            temp = ''
        else:
            temp += d
    return decode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    codes = {}

    a_great_sentence = "The bird is the word"

    print ("The size of the data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(a_great_sentence)))
    print ("The content of the data is: {}\n".format(a_great_sentence))

    encoded_data, tree = huffman_encoding(a_great_sentence)
    # print(tree)
    # print(encoded_data)
    print ("The size of the encoded data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(int(encoded_data, base=2))))
    print ("The content of the encoded data is: {}\n".format(encoded_data))

    decoded_data = huffman_decoding(encoded_data, tree)

    print ("The size of the decoded data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(decoded_data)))
    print ("The content of the decoded data is: {}\n".format(decoded_data))
```

Comment: an empty sentence will throw an exception

Comment: Ad edge case is an extreme condition which may rarely occur, but which your code still has to cater for. Have you tried calling the encoding function with an empty string?

Comment: @Chris Can you please explain more

Comment: Can't convert empty string to int in line `print ("The size of the encoded data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(int(encoded_data, base=2))))
`. Also "perfect and productive" is debatable since global variables are not recommended in python, also writing code directly to main is not recommended (and in my opinion - not very humble).

Comment: @OusStack Changing a_great_sentence = "" will cause the code to crash

Comment: Although the encode/decode functions may work (in the sense that you get what you started with), the encoding scheme that you're using is not Huffman coding. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) for an explanation of Huffman coding.

Comment: @Chris So what I can do about that

Comment: I agree with @user3386109 and I will try to explain why. Take the example where all the chars have nearly the same probability of appearing (but not exactly the same), your code will give each of them a different length whereas Huffman coding would give them about the same length. A good sign to know that the implementation is wrong is when you have a variable named tree that operates as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways you can handle the empty sentence.  A basic if statement on the sentence without any additional conditions will skip the following code if the sentence is empty, and will print the line after the else statement.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    codes = {}

    a_great_sentence = ""

    if a_great_sentence:

        print ("The size of the data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(a_great_sentence)))
        print ("The content of the data is: {}\n".format(a_great_sentence))

        encoded_data, tree = huffman_encoding(a_great_sentence)
        # print(tree)
        # print(encoded_data)
        print ("The size of the encoded data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(int(encoded_data, base=2))))
        print ("The content of the encoded data is: {}\n".format(encoded_data))

        decoded_data = huffman_decoding(encoded_data, tree)

        print ("The size of the decoded data is: {}\n".format(sys.getsizeof(decoded_data)))
        print ("The content of the decoded data is: {}\n".format(decoded_data))

    else:
        print('The sentence is empty, nothing to compute.')
```

Comment: I will try that